# dispatch_async vs dispatch_sync in fetch data. Swift

Tags: swift, concurrency, fetch, dispatch, dispatch-async

After reading so many posts about parallel and concurrent, I still confuse what is the proper way to fetch data. For example, in my project, I have a button for user to fetch data. My code is something like below.

```
var array = [Int]()
func fetchData() {

   ....
   ....
   response(objects: [object], error: NSError?) {
       for object in objects {
           array.append(object.number) // assume object.number return an Int
       }

       // confuse here. Should I use async here because I am worry if the user 
       // click the fetchData button more than one time, the append and make 
       // function will be happened at the same time. Or, is there anything I 
       // made a wrong assumption? I guess I need a serial operation. Correct?

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           makeCollectionView() // using the data in array
       }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tried to run this code. 10000-19999 is run after 0-9999. It seems second async will not stop the first async to process its operation.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    for i in 0 ..< 10000 {
        print(i)
    }
})
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    for i in 10000 ..< 20000 {
         print(i)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCD provides queues for executing tasks. Queues can be of two types – *concurrent* or *serial*. In serial queue tasks execute one at time (in FIFO order), in concurrent queue several tasks at time.

To prevent user fetch data while one fetch task is running, it is needed to not submit fetch task to queue at this moment. No matter what kind of queue is it – concurrent or serial.

```
var array = [Int]()
var isFethingData = false

func fetchData() {
    if !isFethingData {
        isFethingData = true
        dispatch_async(queueForFetchData) {
            …
            response(objects: [object], error: NSError?) {
                for object in objects {
                    array.append(object.number)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    makeCollectionView()
                }
                isFethingData = false
            }
    }
}
```

`dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` is functions which submits tasks to queue. The difference is that `dispatch_async` return immediately after task has been submitted, but `dispatch_sync` wait until task complete. For example:

```
print("\(NSDate()) qq")
dispatch_sync(queue) {
    // … some code which runs for 10 minutes.
    print("\(NSDate()) ee")
}
print("\(NSDate()) ww")
// 2016-08-18 16:02:00 qq
// 2016-08-18 16:12:00 ee
// 2016-08-18 16:12:00 ww


print("\(NSDate()) qq")
dispatch_async(queue) {
    // … some code which runs for 10 minutes.
    print("\(NSDate()) ee")
}
print("\(NSDate()) ww")
// 2016-08-18 16:02:00 qq
// 2016-08-18 16:02:00 ww
// 2016-08-18 16:12:00 ee
```

Comment: Opps. One more question. If I call dispatch_async(queue) {makeCollectionView()} twice, the second makeCollectionView will be run right after the first one or the second one will stop the first one immediately and run? if it will stop the first one immediately, is there any function I can put it as the first task to do in queue?

Comment: @PakHoCheung `dispatch_async` only submit tasks to queue. If you call it twice, then queue will have two tasks more. __Main queue__ is __serial queue__, so tasks will execute if FIFO orded (in your update first will execute 0..1000 loop and second will 10000..20000). If you call dispatch_async on __concurrent queue__ then tasks will run concurrently (for example `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {})`) and you will see print from both loops at same time.

Comment: @PakHoCheung, if you interested in manage tasks (execute, stop, cancel), then you better to look at [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/) and [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/).

Answer (score 1):

to increase performance, anything that involves the UI should run on the main thread. So basically:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       //anything that involves UI
   }
```